# Write a where clause that compares two columns to the same subquery?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to know if it's possible to make a where clause compare 2 columns to the same subquery. I know I could make a temp table/ variable table or write the same subquery twice. But I want to avoid all that if possible. The Subquery is long and complex and will cause significant overhead if I have to write it twice.

Here is an example of what I am trying to do.

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE (Column1 OR Column2) IN (Select column from TABLE)
```

I'm looking for a simple answer and that might just be NO but if it's possible without anything too elaborate please clue me in.

I updated the select to use OR instead of AND as this clarified my question a little better.

Comment: Why a subquery? Why not a proper `join on othertable.col in (this table.col1, this table.col2)`? Even if you only _write_ the subquery once, it still might get evaluated twice. So is your goal least surprise with performance, or easiest on the eyes?

Comment: Perhaps you have oversimplified but by selecting only from Table1 you just need a semi-join so I'd suggest *exists* would work best here.

Answer (score 1):

The example you've given would probably perform best using *exists*, such as:

```
select *
from t1
where exists (
  select 1 from t2 
  where t2.col = t1.col1 and t2.col = t1.col2
);
```

Comment: This assumes that col1 and col2 are a match for the same t2.col value. I'm not quite convinced that is what is needed here, or else OP would/could have used `WHERE Column1 = Column2 and Column2 IN (Select column from TABLE)`, making the question rather unnecessary.

Comment: Yeah, Column1 and Column2 have different IDS but this does give me some ideas to try. Thanks you.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent writing the complicated subquery twice, you can use a [CTE (Common Table Expression)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16):

```
;WITH MyFirstCTE (x) AS
(
   SELECT [column] FROM [TABLE1]
   -- add all the very complicated stuff here
)
SELECT *
FROM   Table2
WHERE  Column1 IN (SELECT x FROM MyFirstCTE)
AND    Column2 IN (SELECT x FROM MyFirstCTE)
```

Or using EXISTS:

```
;WITH MyFirstCTE (x) AS
(
   SELECT [column] FROM [TABLE1]
   -- add all the very complicated stuff here
)
SELECT *
FROM   Table2
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM MyFirstCTE WHERE x = Column1)
AND    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM MyFirstCTE WHERE x = Column2)
```

- I used deliberately clumsy names, best to pick better ones.
- I started it with a `;` because if it's not the first command in a larger script then a `;` is needed to separate the CTE from the commands before it.

Comment: A CTE doesn’t guarantee it will only be evaluated once, it just lets you only _type_ it once.

Comment: (And I only mention that because the OP was worried about “significant overhead” but it’s unclear exactly what overhead they mean.)

Comment: My answer begins with "To prevent writing the complicated subquery twice" and I made no claims about performance, simply hoping that sqlserver will figure out the best strategy.

Comment: Just adding more clarification for other readers.

Comment: This is an option but there is a concern about overhead. Ill look into it though. Thank you for your suggestions.